# Cannot find class [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver] for bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I am trying to get simple spring application with annotation,but i am getting exception when running application...

> SEVERE: Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver] for bean with name 'viewResolver' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1275)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1344)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:910)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1711)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
>       at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:260)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:416)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1296)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1267)
>       ... 19 more

and my files are-

web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID"
version="2.5"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" >

<display-name>SpringTest</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-                            class>
</listener>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
       `    <beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

<bean
    id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
    <property
        name="prefix"
        value="/WEB-INF/JSP/" />

    <property
        name="suffix"
        value=".jsp" />
</bean>

 <context:component-scan base-package="com.controller" />
```

`

i have added below jar in lib folder under WEB-INF

commons-logging-1.1.2.jar,
    org.springframework.aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar,
    org.springframework.asm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar,
    org.springframework.aspects-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar,
    org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar,
    org.springframework.context.support-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar,
    org.springframework.context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar,
    org.springframework.core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar,
    org.springframework.expression-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar,
    org.springframework.transaction-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar,
    org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar,
    org.springframework.web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar

I am not sure why this is happening so plz help me.

i fixed this issue by removing other projects from my server

Comment: first check have you added spring.jar dependency in your classpath.

Comment: have add relevant spring jar into your build path or `pom.xml` in maven?

Comment: Check your packaged war file whether jars are available..

Comment: @DarshanPatel- i have added spring.jar in classpath,but still getting same

Answer (score 1):

Add spring-webmvc jar to classpath

Comment: added spring-webmvc jar but still its giving exception

Comment: Clean your workspace 1 or more type. If not resolved try run server in debug mode. This is bug in Eclipse IDE. Sometime it behaves stange.

Comment: acording to Exception- Cannot find class org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver

whareas its available in "org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"

Comment: i fixed this problem by removing other project from my server.. :)

Answer (score -1):

just change the version of spring framework.
use the version 4.1.5.RELEASE jar

Comment: Try to provide some explanation when making instant leaps at dependency problems.